# I want to delete Linux, and EFI partition is in the way

Tags: partitioning, dualboot

I have a dualboot of W10 and Manjaro and would like to delete Manjaro and only use Windows

Normally I would just delete the Manjaro partitions and extend windows over the unallocated space, however somehow there are two partitions (a recovery partition and the EFI partition) between windows and what would be the unallocated space

[image: Screenshot from the Disk Management tool, sorry for the typo on EFI]

How do I proceed? From what I've read around here deleting EFI could be a bad idea (and I don't know what the recovery partition over there is about), but I do have a recovery unit to repair the W10 boot loader.

My system suports UEFI and has GPT partitions

Comment: If you delete the EFI partition any operating system on the drive won't be able to boot.  You shouldn't delete the recovery partition either.  Both partitions can be moved with third-party disk partition tools.  There are numerous questions that explain that process.  What step are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Just open windows and go to the disks manager or whatever its called. Delete the partitions for the linux and re-size the windows partition. It should take less than 10 minutes!

I didnt read the whole thing before I finished lol. Just download a windows 10 recovery disk just in case and do what you said. Computers are advanced enough to find windows 10. Deleting the bootloader for linux shouldnt be a problem. Windows has a bootloader too, the linux booloader is probably just taking priority over the windows bootloader!